# Compute the limit of this expression of norms:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Compute the limit, as n goes to infinity, of the quotient:

$$\frac{||A^{n+2}(x)||}{||A^n(x)||} $$, given the matrix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 3  \\
        -2 & 5  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

and the vector x = (1,0).

I diagonalized A, found its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and arrive at the expression

$A^{n+2}$ = $SD^{n+2}S^{-1}$ = $$\begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 1  \\
        2 & 1  \\ 
        \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
        2^{n+2} & 0  \\
        0 & 3^{n+2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1  \\
        -2 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$,

where the columns of S form a basis of eigenvectors of A for the 2-dimensional space.

Now, how do I actually compute: $${||A^{n+2}(x)||}?$$

Can I do this (from following my intuition):  $$\begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 1  \\
        2 & 1  \\ 
        \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
        2^{n+2} & 0  \\
        0 & 3^{n+2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1  \\
        -2 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}* (1,0)^T$$,  and then just multiply everything through and arrive at some 2x1 column vector, with entries that depend on n, and then take the usual p-norm for vectors, say, the 2-norm, then take the limit as n goes to infinity?

I tried this method of "brute force", which seems valid, but I am not getting the desired answer.

What's going wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Matrix norms in general aren't multiplicative. You only have $\Vert A B \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert \cdot \Vert B \Vert$.

Comment: This would the be the *sub*-multiplicative property of norms for $||AB|| \leq ||A|| ||B||$.

Comment: ah -- you guys are right.  When do we have equality?  For norms of vectors / modulus of complex numbers / absolute value of real numbers?

Comment: For norms of vectors we have the Cauchy Schwarz inequality, which is similar.  And yes, we have equality for the modulus of complex numbers.

Comment: You've shown that the limit is bounded from *above* by $\|A^2\|$

Comment: ok, thanks @Omnomnomnom -- I just read your comment.  I had thought the initial question would not yield any more comments, so I edited my question just now to include the entire problem that I've been struggling to complete.

Comment: In general: when you have a new question, make a new post, especially if there are already answers given.  In this case, there weren't any answers, so it's not such a big deal.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, you gave a solution to the above problem last night, but can I solve it this way instead?  I feel it would be more instructive for me, but I don't get the answer of 9, like you did (and the solution gives 9 also.) Thanks,

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ok, got it.

Comment: [Link to the other post that mentioned above](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319392/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom -- is it my *choice* of norm that is giving me a different answer, you think?  A question of this type never specifies which norm to use, but we know that all norms are equivalent in a finite-dimensional vector space, so my using the standard 2-norm should be fine, right?

Comment: Note that your method necessarily gives you a lower bound for the vector.  Your choice of $(0,1)^T$ is one of many possible choices, and the norm is, by definition, the maximum over all such choices.

Comment: Oh, the vector is given as (1,0) -- it's not a choice...

Comment: Norms are equivalent, but that doesn't mean that different norms will give you the same answer to this particular question.  "Equivalent" means something that happens to not be useful here.

Comment: The $2 \times 1$ vector:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 3\cdot 2^n-2\cdot 3^n \\
 2^n-4\cdot 3^n \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I have, for $A^{n+2}(x), the 2x1 column vector [ 3*2^{n+2} - 2*3^{n+2} , 2*2^{n+2} - 2*3^{n+2}]^T$

Comment: And for $A^{n}(x), the 2x1 column vector [ 3*2^{n} - 2*3^{n} , 2*2^{n} - 2*3^{n}]^T$

Comment: Now, I am stuck on how to actually take norms of these two 2x1 vectors, and then finally take the limit, as n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\|A^n(x)\|
=
\left\| 
\pmatrix{
 3\cdot 2^n-2\cdot 3^n \\
 2 \cdot 2^n-2\cdot 3^n
}
\right\| = 
3^{n}\left\| 
\pmatrix{
 3\cdot (2/3)^n-2 \\
2\cdot (2/3)^n-2
}
\right\|
$$
and that as $n \to \infty$, we have
$$
\left\| 
\pmatrix{
 3\cdot (2/3)^n-2 \\
2\cdot (2/3)^n-2
}
\right\| \to 
\left\| 
\pmatrix{
-2 \\
-2
}
\right\|
$$

Comment: I think your second row should be $2*2^{n} - 2*3^{n}$ ..

Comment: Well, either way, the general idea is exactly the same.

Comment: Double checked: you're right, fixed it.

Comment: EXCELLENT!!  Thank you SO much, @Omnomnomnom.  I arrived at $3^{2}$ = 9 :-).